# How to fix TypeScript React props types when passing components as variables?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings

I am passing React components as variables and trying to protect myself from runtime errors with correct types. The problem is that when I need to instantiate component from variable, the prop-types feels 'inverted'. The following snippet will better illustrate problem.

And also the solution I found - wrapping component with functional component, that just passes props through

```
interface IBaseStore {
  prop: number;
}
interface IExtendedStore extends IBaseStore {
  extraProp: number;
}
type ComponentProps<StoreT> = {
  store: StoreT;
};
const BaseComponent = (props: ComponentProps<IBaseStore>) => <div>{props.store.prop}</div>;
const ExtendedComponent = (props: ComponentProps<IExtendedStore>) => <div>{props.store.extraProp}</div>;

type ConfigProps<StoreT> = {
  additionalLayer: ComponentType<ComponentProps<StoreT>>;
};
const tableConfigCorrect1: ConfigProps<IBaseStore> = {
  additionalLayer: BaseComponent,
};
const tableConfigCorrect2: ConfigProps<IExtendedStore> = {
  additionalLayer: BaseComponent,
};

const tableConfigWrongType1: ConfigProps<IBaseStore> = {
  additionalLayer: ExtendedComponent, // No TS error
};
const runtimeError = <tableConfigWrongType1.additionalLayer store={{ prop: 5 }}/>;
// Solution:
const tableConfigWrongType2: ConfigProps<IBaseStore> = {
  additionalLayer: props => <ExtendedComponent {...props}/>, // TS error, not compiled
};
```

Feels like its kind of common OOP problem with 'inverted' subtypes and Im looking for some pattern or TS typing to solve it in cleaner way

Answer (score 0):

I broke this down a bit, and yes, there seems to be a loophole in the typescript error checker. This isn't a solution, but I can simplify the problem into a clearer example. Here is your bit of code where there should be an error:

```
const tableConfigWrongType1: ConfigProps<IBaseStore> = {
    additionalLayer: ExtendedComponent, // No TS error
};
```

Let's break it down:

```
// Unwrapping ConfigProps<StoreT> and just looking at additionalLayer:
// Also, I replaced ExtendedComponent with its implementation.
let additionalLayer: React.ComponentType<ComponentProps<IBaseStore>>;
additionalLayer = (props: ComponentProps<IExtendedStore>) => <div />; // No error
```

Simplifying this further:

```
// Unwrapping ComponentProps
let additionalLayer: React.ComponentType<{ store: IBaseStore; }>;
additionalLayer = (props: { store: IExtendedStore; }) => <div />;
```

And then breaking down IBaseStore and IExtendedStore:

```
let additionalLayer: React.ComponentType<{ store: {prop: number}; }>;
additionalLayer = (props: { store: {prop: number; extraProp: number}; }) => <div />;
```

And then replacing ComponentType with its functional implementation (simplified):

```
let additionalLayer: (props: { store: {prop: number} }) => React.ReactElement | null;
additionalLayer = (props: { store: {prop: number; extraProp: number} }) => <div />;
```

There is still no error, which I find puzzling. Now I can simplify it down to a more simple example:

```
// This function takes a callback that requires an object with `a`.
function callWithA (cb: (obj: {a: number}) => void) {
    cb({a: 5});
}
// But we can pass a callback that expects more than `a`.
declare let callbackThatNeedsAAndB: (obj: {a: number, b: number}) => void;
callWithA(callbackThatNeedsAAndB); // No error but should be an error.
```

However, if the properties are separated into parameters, it correctly shows an error:

```
function callWithA_separate (cb: (a: number) => void) {
    cb(5);
}
declare let callbackThatNeedsAAndB_separate: (a: number, b: number) => void;
callWithA_separate(callbackThatNeedsAAndB_separate);
// Error: Argument of type '(a: number, b: number) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(a: number) => void'. ts(2345)
```

This might be what's going on: see the Typescript FAQ entry called [why are function parameters bivariant](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-function-parameters-bivariant)

I hope this shed some light on the issue. Again, this isn't a solution but hopefully it's useful for understanding the issue.

Comment: Thanks. I found that bivariant parameter check can be disabled by strictFunctionTypes flag. But then we cant use also its props